# Unable to Install or Update Packagist package "twbs/bootstrap" with composer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, composer-php, packagist, jasny-bootstrap

I work on a French version of WindowsNT (I stated that you are not surprised by the names in French like "Mes Documents").

I want to add the ["twbs/bootstrap"](https://packagist.org/packages/twbs/bootstrap) package in my symfony2 project. Like I've done a hundred times before, I've add the line :

```
"twbs/bootstrap": "dev-master",
```

In the "require" section of my "composer.json" file located in the root of my project.

This is a copy of my "composer.json" file :

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "gregwar/captcha-bundle": "dev-master",
        "mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*@dev",
        "craue/formflow-bundle": "dev-master",
        "twitter/bootstrap": "v3.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I enter the following command in my command prompt :

```
> CD [project_root]
>"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.exe" "[composer_dir]\composer.phar" self-update 
You are already using composer version 4ec4ba1397e7cc07c0986d866b62397091e7d20d.
>"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.exe" "[composer_dir]\composer.phar" "--no-interaction" "update" "--dev" -vvv > composer-log.log 2>&1
```

And this is the resulting log file (composer-log.log) :

```
Reading ./composer.json
Executing command (CWD): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Loading composer repositories with package information
Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
Writing %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Downloading https://packagist.org/p/provider-active$c9b925fde76c682bbb9b60faffed20f3cacc2cf5556f12fd45dec91b83f401d3.json
Writing %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-active.json into cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-archived.json from cache
Downloading https://packagist.org/p/provider-latest$8fd2e34b72514bcb6126df884cc31c37d686ab44149914a5002486dccd9e84c4.json
Writing %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json into cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-stale.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$framework-standard-edition.json from cache
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$symfony.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$orm.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$doctrine-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-twig$extensions.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$assetic-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$swiftmailer-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$monolog-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-sensio$distribution-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-sensio$framework-extra-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-sensio$generator-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-incenteev$composer-parameter-handler.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-jms$security-extra-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$data-fixtures.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$doctrine-fixtures-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-friendsofsymfony$user-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-gregwar$captcha-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-mopa$bootstrap-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-twbs$bootstrap.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-knplabs$knp-paginator-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-knplabs$knp-menu-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-knplabs$knp-menu.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-craue$formflow-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-twitter$bootstrap.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$lexer.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$annotations.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$common.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$cache.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$inflector.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$collections.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-twig$twig.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-psr$log.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$icu.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$browser-kit.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$class-loader.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$config.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$console.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$css-selector.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$debug.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$dependency-injection.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$doctrine-bridge.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$dom-crawler.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$event-dispatcher.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$expression-language.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$filesystem.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$finder.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$form.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$framework-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$http-foundation.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$http-kernel.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$intl.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$locale.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$monolog-bridge.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$options-resolver.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$process.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$propel1-bridge.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$property-access.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$proxy-manager-bridge.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$routing.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$security.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$security-acl.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$security-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$security-core.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$security-csrf.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$security-http.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$serializer.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$stopwatch.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$swiftmailer-bridge.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$templating.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$translation.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$twig-bridge.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$twig-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$validator.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$web-profiler-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$yaml.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-jdorn$sql-formatter.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$dbal.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-monolog$monolog.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-swiftmailer$swiftmailer.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$doctrine-abstract-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$doctrine-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-gregwar$captcha.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-jms$cg.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-phpoption$phpoption.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-jms$parser-lib.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-jms$metadata.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-jms$aop-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-jms$di-extra-bundle.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-silex$silex.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-igorw$config-service-provider.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-cilex$console-service-provider.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-justinrainbow$json-schema.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-mlebkowski$crane.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-pimple$pimple.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-kriswallsmith$assetic.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-mopa$composer-bridge.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-knplabs$knp-components.json from cache
Reading %APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-jasny$bootstrap.json from cache
  - Installing twbs/bootstrap (dev-master 3a62811)
    Cloning 3a62811bbde4e428df1882bddf940f40381a8d41
Executing command (CWD): git clone "git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git" "C:\wamp\www\PORTAL\DEV2\vendor\twbs/bootstrap" && cd /D "C:\wamp\www\PORTAL\DEV2\vendor\twbs/bootstrap" && git remote add composer "git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git" && git fetch composer



  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]               
  The process "git clone "git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git" "C:\wamp\www\P  
  ORTAL\DEV2\vendor\twbs/bootstrap" && cd /D "C:\wamp\www\PORTAL\DEV2\vendor\  
  twbs/bootstrap" && git remote add composer "git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap  
  .git" && git fetch composer" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.            



Exception trace:
 () at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php:984
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->checkTimeout() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php:256
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->start() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php:198
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->run() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/ProcessExecutor.php:61
 Composer\Util\ProcessExecutor->execute() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/src/Composer/Downloader/GitDownloader.php:323
 Composer\Downloader\GitDownloader->runCommand() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/src/Composer/Downloader/GitDownloader.php:43
 Composer\Downloader\GitDownloader->doDownload() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/src/Composer/Downloader/VcsDownloader.php:59
 Composer\Downloader\VcsDownloader->download() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/src/Composer/Downloader/DownloadManager.php:182
 Composer\Downloader\DownloadManager->download() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php:155
 Composer\Installer\LibraryInstaller->installCode() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php:86
 Composer\Installer\LibraryInstaller->install() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:153
 Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->install() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:140
 Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->execute() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:515
 Composer\Installer->doInstall() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:210
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:123
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:241
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:881
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:191
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:117
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://%HOMEPATH%/Mes documents/NetBeansProjects/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
 require() at %HOMEPATH%\Mes documents\NetBeansProjects\composer.phar:15


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

And this is the "%APPDATA%/Composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-jasny$bootstrap.json" file (I think the problem come from here) :

```
{"packages":{"jasny\/bootstrap":{"dev-gh-pages":
{"name":"jasny\/bootstrap","description":"An extended version of Twitter Bootstrap","keywords":["css","bootstrap"],"homepage":"http:\/\/jasny.github.io\/bootstrap","version":"dev-gh-pages","version_normalized":"dev-gh-pages","license":["Apache-2.0"],"authors":[{"name":"Arnold Daniels","email":"arnold@jasny.net","homepage":"http:\/\/www.jasny.net"}
,{"name":"Jacob Thornton","email":"jacobthornton@gmail.com"}
,{"name":"Mark Otto","email":"markdotto@gmail.com"}
],"source":{"type":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/jasny\/bootstrap.git","reference":"fcf399801646abb4e978672b2efe69343aa9170b"}
,"dist":{"type":"zip","url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/jasny\/bootstrap\/zipball\/fcf399801646abb4e978672b2efe69343aa9170b","reference":"fcf399801646abb4e978672b2efe69343aa9170b","shasum":""}
,"type":"library","time":"2013-11-18T21:31:57+00:00","replace":{"twitter\/bootstrap":"3.0.0"}
,"uid":95714}
,"dev-master":{"name":"jasny\/bootstrap","description":"An extended version of Twitter Bootstrap","keywords":["css","bootstrap"],"homepage":"http:\/\/jasny.github.io\/bootstrap","version":"dev-master","version_normalized":"9999999-dev","license":["Apache-2.0"],"authors":[{"name":"Arnold Daniels","email":"arnold@jasny.net","homepage":"http:\/\/www.jasny.net"}
,{"name":"Jacob Thornton","email":"jacobthornton@gmail.com"}
,{"name":"Mark Otto","email":"markdotto@gmail.com"}
],"source":{"type":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/jasny\/bootstrap.git","reference":"371f6d510ba7c7bd6387d45cc7df6fb5973ce89c"}
,"dist":{"type":"zip","url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/jasny\/bootstrap\/zipball\/371f6d510ba7c7bd6387d45cc7df6fb5973ce89c","reference":"371f6d510ba7c7bd6387d45cc7df6fb5973ce89c","shasum":""}
,"type":"library","time":"2014-01-22T19:38:24+00:00","replace":{"twitter\/bootstrap":"3.0.0"}
,"uid":68558}
,"v2.2.2-p3":{"name":"jasny\/bootstrap","description":"Sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development.","keywords":["css","bootstrap"],"homepage":"http:\/\/jasny.github.com\/bootstrap\/","version":"v2.2.2-p3","version_normalized":"2.2.2.0-patch3","license":["Apache-2.0"],"authors":[{"name":"Arnold Daniels","email":"arnold@jasny.net","homepage":"http:\/\/www.jasny.net"}
,{"name":"Twitter Inc."}
],"source":{"type":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/jasny\/bootstrap.git","reference":"3ab1bb7e4a539066c0fb8840fe0b22b6385a7579"}
,"dist":{"type":"zip","url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/jasny\/bootstrap\/zipball\/3ab1bb7e4a539066c0fb8840fe0b22b6385a7579","reference":"3ab1bb7e4a539066c0fb8840fe0b22b6385a7579","shasum":""}
,"type":"library","time":"2013-07-12T12:02:23+00:00","target-dir":"jasny\/bootstrap","replace":{"twitter\/bootstrap":"2.2.2"}
,"uid":68568}
,"v2.3.0-p4":{"name":"jasny\/bootstrap","description":"Sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development.","keywords":["css","bootstrap"],"homepage":"http:\/\/jasny.github.com\/bootstrap\/","version":"v2.3.0-p4","version_normalized":"2.3.0.0-patch4","license":["Apache-2.0"],"authors":[{"name":"Arnold Daniels","email":"arnold@jasny.net","homepage":"http:\/\/www.jasny.net"}
,{"name":"Twitter Inc."}
],"source":{"type":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/jasny\/bootstrap.git","reference":"9ec4b5736e226b0e517797709ac1feb6bd0c31d2"}
,"dist":{"type":"zip","url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/jasny\/bootstrap\/zipball\/9ec4b5736e226b0e517797709ac1feb6bd0c31d2","reference":"9ec4b5736e226b0e517797709ac1feb6bd0c31d2","shasum":""}
,"type":"library","time":"2013-07-12T12:03:30+00:00","replace":{"twitter\/bootstrap":"2.3.0"}
,"uid":68569}
,"v2.3.0-p5":{"name":"jasny\/bootstrap","description":"Sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development.","keywords":["css","bootstrap"],"homepage":"http:\/\/jasny.github.com\/bootstrap\/","version":"v2.3.0-p5","version_normalized":"2.3.0.0-patch5","license":["Apache-2.0"],"authors":[{"name":"Arnold Daniels","email":"arnold@jasny.net","homepage":"http:\/\/www.jasny.net"}
,{"name":"Twitter Inc."}
],"source":{"type":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/jasny\/bootstrap.git","reference":"5f7af187b56a29404489609908ee9689437bb4b1"}
,"dist":{"type":"zip","url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/jasny\/bootstrap\/zipball\/5f7af187b56a29404489609908ee9689437bb4b1","reference":"5f7af187b56a29404489609908ee9689437bb4b1","shasum":""}
,"type":"library","time":"2013-07-12T12:03:00+00:00","replace":{"twitter\/bootstrap":"2.3.0"}
,"uid":68570}
,"v2.3.1-p6":{"name":"jasny\/bootstrap","description":"Sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development.","keywords":["css","bootstrap"],"homepage":"http:\/\/jasny.github.com\/bootstrap\/","version":"v2.3.1-p6","version_normalized":"2.3.1.0-patch6","license":["Apache-2.0"],"authors":[{"name":"Arnold Daniels","email":"arnold@jasny.net","homepage":"http:\/\/www.jasny.net"}
,{"name":"Twitter Inc."}
],"source":{"type":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/jasny\/bootstrap.git","reference":"c681d5016e67e1aaa2b07a80da45e9ea67e6b924"}
,"dist":{"type":"zip","url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/jasny\/bootstrap\/zipball\/c681d5016e67e1aaa2b07a80da45e9ea67e6b924","reference":"c681d5016e67e1aaa2b07a80da45e9ea67e6b924","shasum":""}
,"type":"library","time":"2013-07-12T11:58:09+00:00","replace":{"twitter\/bootstrap":"2.3.1"}
,"uid":68571}
,"v3.0.0-p7":{"name":"jasny\/bootstrap","description":"An extended version of Twitter Bootstrap","keywords":["css","bootstrap"],"homepage":"http:\/\/jasny.github.io\/bootstrap","version":"v3.0.0-p7","version_normalized":"3.0.0.0-patch7","license":["Apache-2.0"],"authors":[{"name":"Arnold Daniels","email":"arnold@jasny.net","homepage":"http:\/\/www.jasny.net"}
,{"name":"Jacob Thornton","email":"jacobthornton@gmail.com"}
,{"name":"Mark Otto","email":"markdotto@gmail.com"}
],"source":{"type":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/jasny\/bootstrap.git","reference":"fbad6209c493234142ef2ee11b6f69c2053a2888"}
,"dist":{"type":"zip","url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/jasny\/bootstrap\/zipball\/fbad6209c493234142ef2ee11b6f69c2053a2888","reference":"fbad6209c493234142ef2ee11b6f69c2053a2888","shasum":""}
,"type":"library","time":"2013-10-29T23:32:28+00:00","replace":{"twitter\/bootstrap":"3.0.0"}
,"uid":95716}
,"v3.0.1-p7":{"name":"jasny\/bootstrap","description":"An extended version of Twitter Bootstrap","keywords":["css","bootstrap"],"homepage":"http:\/\/jasny.github.io\/bootstrap","version":"v3.0.1-p7","version_normalized":"3.0.1.0-patch7","license":["Apache-2.0"],"authors":[{"name":"Arnold Daniels","email":"arnold@jasny.net","homepage":"http:\/\/www.jasny.net"}
,{"name":"Jacob Thornton","email":"jacobthornton@gmail.com"}
,{"name":"Mark Otto","email":"markdotto@gmail.com"}
],"source":{"type":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/jasny\/bootstrap.git","reference":"a977d5ce6a2ab6f77d9f57559fc3ae2b4ab77d37"}
,"dist":{"type":"zip","url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/jasny\/bootstrap\/zipball\/a977d5ce6a2ab6f77d9f57559fc3ae2b4ab77d37","reference":"a977d5ce6a2ab6f77d9f57559fc3ae2b4ab77d37","shasum":""}
,"type":"library","time":"2013-11-01T19:54:20+00:00","replace":{"twitter\/bootstrap":"3.0.0"}
,"uid":97356}
}
}
}
```

After the error I've try to manualy finish the git pull of the "twbs/bootstrap" package by the following commands :

```
> CD vendor\twbs\bootstrap
> git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

So it seems that the download of the package has been completed and the only problem come from the update of the composer cache and I've no idea why.

For your information my composer still working when I try to update other package or install new ones. ["twbs/bootstrap"](https://packagist.org/packages/twbs/bootstrap) is the only one that cause this problem.

If you can give me ideas to solve this problem I would be very grateful to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a stable **tagged** version of bootstrap to your `composer.json`:

```
"require":
    "twbs/bootstrap": "3.0.3"
```

or just run:

```
composer require twbs/bootstrap:3.0.3
```

Otherwise any bootstrap updates can easily break your application as new features (breaking backward compatibility) might be introduced.

Now - instead of updating the dependencies using the git protocol - you can tell composer to download your dependency's **dist** zip-package instead. This often helps if you experience connection-problems or timeouts.

```
composer update twbs/bootstrap --prefer-dist --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```